# Using webdriver PageFactory to pick certain page

Tags: c#, webdriver, pageobjects

I have a web project where clicking a button navigates to another page. The new page can be 1 of three possible pages depending on data in the server. (The url may be the same for 2 of those pages)

I have three classes representing expected elements on each page using the PageObject model.

What is the best way to actually find what page actually got loaded? Is there an OR type of wait that I can wait on three unique elements and get the one that actually got loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to check the presence of unique element (which identifies the page) and then return respective page in the framework.

However, a test should know the page it is expecting next and should assume that the correct page has loaded and perform further actions/assertions. You can even put an assertion here to verify correct page has loaded. If a different page has loaded, then the test eventually fails as assertions would fail.
This way test becomes more readable and describes flow of application.

Also, setting up test data upfront for the tests, is always advisable. This way you would know what data is available on server and test would know which page would render.

Comment: In this case, it would be a bit hard to know which  page to expect next, since the application uses OAuth and reroutes to the OAuth provider and the user accounts that the tests use may or may not already have given permission for that application since the user pool is shared between different tests

Comment: Ok. If that's the case, we have to write C# code which checks for existence of these unique elements (post the page has rendered) and return corresponding page object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to detect if a login was for a new user (the login page then goes to a terms & conditions page rather than direct to the home page).

Initially I just waited and then tested the second page but this was just a pain so I came up with this.

To Test the result with this:

```
var whichScreen = waitForEitherElementText(By.CssSelector(HeaderCssUsing), "HOME SCREEN", "home", terms.getHeaderLocator(), terms.headerText, "terms", driver, MAX_STALE_RETRIES);

        if(whichScreen.Item1 && whichScreen.Item2 == "terms")
        {
            terms.aggreeToTerms();
        }
```

The method that this calls is :

```
    protected Tuple<bool, string> waitForEitherElementText(By locator1, string expectedText1, string return1Ident,
        By locator2, string expectedText2, string return2Ident, IWebDriver driver, int retries)
    {
        var retryCount = 0;
        string returnText = "";
        WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(globalWaitTime));
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        while (retryCount < retries)
        {
            try
            {
                explicitWait.Until<bool>((d) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Equals(d.FindElement(locator1).Text, expectedText1)) { returnText = return1Ident; };
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        if (Equals(d.FindElement(locator2).Text, expectedText2)) { returnText = return2Ident; };
                    }
                    return (returnText != "");
                });
                return Tuple.Create(true, returnText);
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString() +
                    ":>>> -" + locator1.ToString() + " OR " + locator2.ToString() + "- <<< - " +
                    this.GetType().FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name +
                    " : " + e.Message);
                retryCount++;
            }
        }
        return Tuple.Create(false,"");
    }
```

The explicit wait until uses a boolean so will loop around for the full wait time (I have a very slow Test server so I set this to 60 seconds).  the implicit wait is set to half a second so the element tests will attempt every half a second and loop around until either true is returned or it fails.
I use a Tuple so that I can detect which screen I am on, and in this case agree to the terms & conditions which then sets me back on my normal page path